# Converting Special Characters into alphabet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with Name column which is in different language.I need to convert this names into Standard English language.

Example:

HỒ ĐĂNG TẤN has to be converted to HO DANG TAN.

NGUYỄN ĐỨC KIÊN - NGUYEN DUC KIEN

ĐOÀN THỊ THANH THẢO- DOAN THI THANH

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Step 1:** Open Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window.

**Step 2:** Click Insert -> Module, and enter the following macro in the Module Window.

```
Function StripAccent(thestring As String)
Dim A As String * 1
Dim B As String * 1
Dim i As Integer

Const AccChars= "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
Const RegChars= "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"

For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
A = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)
B = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
thestring = Replace(thestring, A, B)
Next
StripAccent = thestring
End Function
```

**Step 3:** Then go to a blank cell and paste the formula in a cell: 
`=CheckStringCHAR(InString)`
for example `=CheckStringCHAR("ù")`, or `=CheckStringCHAR(A2)`.

The list of characters is not exhaustive. more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin-script_letters#Letters_with_diacritics

Comment: like this answer, too... +1

Comment: @mehow still a poor question has an answer.

Comment: @Rishi Ễ,Ư,Ờ,Ậ,Ị,Ầ,Ă,Ỹ,Đ,Ặ,Ệ,Ố etc. This characters are not converted.Even when you add this characters ist not considered as a special character.Consider the second example which I have provided so is there any other way to add this characters.

Comment: @user2230817 normally your question would get marked as not constructive and probably closed. its your lucky day - enjoy!;)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it, the below is a more efficient version of the function that is doing the rounds on the web pasted above as an answer.

Sample test results (100 loops of a 10,000 char strings). Times are milliseconds per call, picked up from QueryPerformanceTimer.

Old: Min: 57.6 ms, Mean: 65.4 ms

New: Min: 22.1 ms, Mean: 24.4 ms

The performance improvement comes from not creating new copies of the string at each replace, by instead replacing the characters in-place using the Mid$ statement.

```
Public Function StripAccent(ByVal txt As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Const c1 = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
    Const c2 = "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"
    n = Len(c1)
    For i = 1 To n
        j = 0
        Do
            j = InStr(j + 1, txt, Mid$(c1, i, 1), vbBinaryCompare)
            If j > 0 Then Mid$(txt, j, 1) = Mid$(c2, i, 1) Else Exit Do
        Loop
    Next
    StripAccent = txt
End Function
```