# Dynamic variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, formula, quotes

I have this VBA Script and I don't know how to make dynamic the bold section, so that the formula would be `=StripAccent(C2)`, `=StripAccent(C3)` and so on for each `i`.

```
For i = 2 To 10  
    Cells(i, 5) = "=StripAccent(Ci)"
Next i
```

I read about double quotes, but it didn't work there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim i    As Long
    For i = 2 To 10
        Cells(i, 5) = "=StripAccent(C" & i & ")"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Another one is to use `Cells(i,3)`.

**Edit:** If you are using a custom function from here - [Converting Special Characters into alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184577/converting-special-characters-into-alphabet) then something like this can work as well (but not as a formula):

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim i    As Long
    For i = 2 To 10
        Cells(i, 5) = StripAccent(Cells(i,3))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you don't need a loop, you can directly add the `Formula` to your entire range, like this:

```
Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(10, 5)).Formula = "=StripAccent(C2)"
```

Or, even "cleaner" :

```
Range("E2:E10").Formula = "=StripAccent(C2)"
```

Comment: @Vityata where did he mention he needs a loop? I think he wants the fomrula dragged according to the row number in column "E"

Comment: Seems legit in a way.

Answer (score 1):

```
For i = 2 To 10  
    Cells(i, 5).Formula = "=StripAccent(C" & i & ")"
Next i
```